# Выборка m записей с n записи

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Нужно составить такой MySQL запрос: "Выбрать в обратном порядке `m` записей из базы, начиная с `n` записи".

Написал так:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id > $pos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Но я думаю, что так писать не стоит, и есть более правильная форма запроса.

Comment: Запрос работает так, как предполагалось? Что именно вас не устраивает в запросе?

Comment: Если записей будет много то это не оптимально так как придется проходить всю таблицу пока не дойдем до нужного ид

Comment: Добавьте индекс (если его ещё нет) на поле `id`. Если вам нужно выбрать первые пять строк, `id` которых больше определённого значения и которые имеют максимальные `id` среди всех найденных записей, то запрос такой и должен быть.

Comment: Если же вам надо отсортировать данные по убыванию `id` и взять 5 записей с 10 места, а `WHERE id > $pos` используется для этого в качестве костыля, то можно поменять запрос на `SELECT * FROM items  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9, 5`

Comment: http://myrusakov.ru/sql-limit.html

Comment: @Regent Пожалуйста, оформите ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это не так, что я снова взялся за старое и размещаю ответы в комментариях. Тут проблема в том, что так и непонятно что вообще нужно автору.

Answer (score 1):

Если база данных предполагает удаление строк, то такую выборку делать бессмысленно. Если строки удаляться не будут, то запрос должен быть такого вида:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE id >= n AND id <= n+m ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT m
```